# Dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3.3.6 not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to programming and I decided to run a little test on Bootstrap 3.3.6 but the dropdown menu is not working. I tried using the CDN links as well both for bootstrap and the script but it's not not working.
What am I missing? Here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#skills">Skills<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                   <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                   <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                   <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#schools">Schools</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact Me<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
           </ul>         
          </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
```

What is wrong with these code or I'm missing something?

Answer (score -1):

- You are missing to Include CDN Files into Header tag. Replace below header tag with your code and try.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Notestrap</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#skills">Skills<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#schools">Schools</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact Me<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He is asking for  bootstrap version 3.3.6 not 3.3.7... If he change it to 3.3.7 everything goes wrong with style..